# Generate PDF file Using Apache Fop Java

Tags: java, pdf-generation

Im trying to generate a pdf file using FOUserAgent in Java

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream generateReport() {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(errorData, sw);
        InputStream xsltFile = new ClassPathResource("/location/template/fil.xls").getInputStream();
StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sw.toString()));
    
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
  
    FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));

      Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
      transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
return out;

}
```

Report is generated. But when trying to open the pdf file following error is prompted.
**There was an error opening this document. File is damaged and could not be repaired.**

I can't see why it's giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add error listener like this:

```
public class PdfTransformerErrorListener implements ErrorListener {
    @Override
    public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        log.warn(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        log.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
        log.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
    }
}
```

and use this class like that:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(templateStream); // template stream is fop file that you use, to generate a pdf
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(source); // identity
transformer.setErrorListener(new PdfTransformerErrorListener());
```

Of course, put the generation code to try/catch and print out the exception.